# Error al intentar recuperar dato relacionado Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Tengo definido un modelo Premios que además de sus atributos tiene una funcion puntos() que trae el último puntaje de su historial asociado. Desde tinker recupero el puntaje sin problemas con:

**$premio->puntos();**

**=> 200**

Pero desde la vista,
**{{ $premio->puntos() }}**
me devuelve: **Call to undefined method stdClass::puntos() (View: ...**

El objeto **$premio** existe y recupero todos los demás datos perfectamente.

**Modelo Premio**

```
class Premio extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombre', 'descripcion', 'status', 'picture'];

public function puntos()
{
    return $this->ultimosPuntos->first()->puntos;
}

public function ultimosPuntos()
{
    // Obtengo los últimos 10 puntos
    return $this->hasMany(PuntosPremio::class)
        ->skip(0)
        ->take(10)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

}

Comment: {{ $premio->puntos }} has probado sin el parentesis??